# Java:Cannot load main class with jar file using classpath

Tags: java, executable-jar

I am getting error while executing a jar file.
I have set  my manifest file with a new line and it looks  like this:

```
Main-Class: Demo
Class-Path: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar .
```

My Main class name is Demo and it is in the current working directory.
When I execute `jar cfm Project.jar manifest.txt *.class`

My Error is:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Demo
```

There is no problem with main classname and executing Directory because when I execute the jar file without classpath I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
        at Demo.main(Demo.java:8)
```

Comment: Your Demo class has no package?

Comment: give the complete package name of Demo

Comment: and can you show us the exact command you run that gives you this error ?

Comment: Is it ok to have absolute path in manifest? I have not seen it yet.

Comment: can you try the `set classpath=` syntax at the command line instead of hardcoding it inside the manifest? It might not be a good idea anyway (forcing users to have the jar file in a pre-determined path).

Comment: I am using the default package

Comment: Classpath is already set in system environment variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [JAR File Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) (Under "Main Attributes", "Class-Path" the path should be relative not absolute. So if you copy the oracle jdbc jar to the same directory as your jar file, and change the path to just "ojdbc14.jar", it should work.